# Git change the repo path of a subfolder

Tags: git, github, repository, git-submodules, git-subtree

I've got a git structure like the following:

```
/web_app
-- /static
-- /templates
-- app.py
```

Having this, when i push to my repo, its pushed following exactly that folder structure, but what I want in the repo is this structure:

```
/web_app
--  /web
    -- /static
    -- /template
-- app.py
```

So what I want to do is somehow, from my folder in my pc push the folders `/static` and `/templates` into /web/ in repo, and when pulling or clonning, keep the original folder structure.

I've been searching trough docs for `submodules` and `subtrees` but either I didn't understand well how they work or they don't satisfy my necessities.

So, Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first recommendation is to download [the git cheat sheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftraining.github.com%2Fkit%2Fdownloads%2Fgithub-git-cheat-sheet.pdf&ei=1oxrVNXQN4ScNtX8gtgK&usg=AFQjCNHip6PRB0h9pd15mCXk5dPYEGLQlA&sig2=duSNDafSvCGRgqWCD3DQkQ) and keep it handy on your desktop.

The command to accomplish what you want to do is `git mv <source> <destination>.` in the shell. The [documentation for the command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) states that it will work on directories.

In your case, this means, from the /web_app directory, you should make your "web" directory:

```
md web
```

Then you should move your directories

```
git mv ./static ./web/static
git mv ./template ./web/template
```

Comment: I see that I misunderstood. You could create client-side git hooks which run when you push or pull. However, I believe it would be hard to get this to work correctly. You would probably end up placing the files in the wrong location. So I think, no, you cannot accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

What I finnally did was the following:

I created a new Repo, and with git submodule modularized /web.

It solves my problem, but for real problem I posted, check M. K. Hunter option